# Explain output for c(0:5)[NA]

Tags: r, vector, subset, na

`c(0:5)[1]` is 0.

`c(0:5)[2]` is 1.

But for the code

```
c(0:5)[NA]
```

The output is

> ```
> [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
> ```

Why is R showing 6 NAs as output?

Answer (score 0):

The `c` in `c(0:5)` is redundant. `0:5` is already a vector. You would still need parentheses around `0:5` in `(0:5)[NA]` because of operator precedence.

The exact reason for what you see here depends on the implementation of `[]`, but the result makes intuitive sense. `[]` isn't just used to extract single elements, it is used to extract subsets. If the index vector is unavailable, then for each element of the original vector, its status in the subset you are trying to extract is unavailable as well.